# MongoDb with SpringData - global setting to create all indexes in background

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

We are using:

- spring-data-mongodb version 1.7.2.RELEASE (but we are open for upgrading)
- spring version 4.2.6.RELEASE (but we are open for upgrading)
- MongoDB version 3.2.8 (Not sure about upgrade options at the moment but let's say it is also an option)

We create indices on collections using the @Indexed annotation (for simple and compound indices)

We want to prevent foreground creation new indices, and I want to know if there is a flag or option to set in MongoDB's configuration or in Spring's Mongo connection that can globally set all indices to be background, even if they were not defined as such in Java code (annotation)?

The rreason I'm asking is that we had an issue that a POJO was moved from one class to another, and this caused an index in that POJO to be created in the foreground. I'm looking for a way to prevent this scenario from happening again, and also prevent other developers from accidentally adding foreground indices in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have asked a Mongo DB consultant who came to give us a session on some Mongo DB internals.
His answer was that there is no such setting or flag for Mongo DB, so this means that Spring Data probably hasn't such a setting or flag..

Off to manually change our code so all our indices to background.

Comment: The fact that MongoDB server doesn't have a global flag shouldn't preclude Spring Data from having a setting in `AbstractMongoConfiguration` or similar

Comment: @NicCottrell - I tired searching for setting anything related to indexes and AbstractMongoConfiguration, and got nothing helpful.
Do you know of such an option? Can you please link to an example or show a code snippet with one?

Comment: I looked myself with no luck. So I just created a new ticket https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1895

Answer (score 1):

You can set various options with `@Indexed` but you can't change globally the behavior. `@Indexed` has a limited feature scope and it's intended for simple use cases.

You should rather use `IndexOperations` to get full control over index creation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did a short search on 'IndexOperations' and seems that I still need to set each index options on its own - so no central flag or option to do this yet.